# int variable should have value 45, is printed as 2358648

Tags: c

How this answer is come

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
int main() {
    int i, sum;
    for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < 10; i++)
        sum += i;
    printf("%d", & sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2358648
```

Comment: Don't pass `sum` as a pointer to printf - remove the `&`

Comment: Your program needs to go on a diet; it's too short and fat.

Comment: What answer do you *expect*? It may be obvious to you but not us because we cannot read your mind :)

Comment: Compile  with warnings enabled: `gcc -Wall -Werror` would tell you immediately about this silly mistake.

Comment: You don't need non standard `<conio.h>`

Comment: `printf("%d", & sum);` is undefined behavior due to type mismatch.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing addess instead of value

just remove `&` in `printf`

```
printf("%d",sum);
```

Comment: assalamu alaikum why we not use & operator

Comment: @SamirNarang: Because `&` returns the address of an object, and you don't want to print the address of the object but its value.

Comment: @SamirNarang walaikum assalam ..  Christian Hackl already gave answer.